# pandas: time difference in groupby

Tags: time, pandas-groupby, difference

How to calculate time difference for each id between current row and next for
dataset below:

```
time                    id

2012-03-16 23:50:00      1
2012-03-16 23:56:00      1
2012-03-17 00:08:00      1
2012-03-17 00:10:00      2
2012-03-17 00:12:00      2
2012-03-17 00:20:00      2
2012-03-20 00:43:00      3
```

and get next result:

```
time                    id       tdiff
2012-03-16 23:50:00      1         6  
2012-03-16 23:56:00      1         12  
2012-03-17 00:08:00      1         NA
2012-03-17 00:10:00      2         2 
2012-03-17 00:12:00      2         8    
2012-03-17 00:20:00      2         NA 
2012-03-20 00:43:00      3         NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you need result in minutes by `id`. Here is how to do it :

use `diff()` in groupby :

```
# first convert to datetime with the right format 
data['time']=pd.to_datetime(data.time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
data['tdiff']=(data.groupby('id').diff().time.values/60000000000).astype(int)
data['tdiff'][data['tdiff'] < 0] = np.nan
print(data)
```

output

```
                 time  id  tdiff
0 2012-03-16 23:50:00   1    NaN
1 2012-03-16 23:56:00   1    6.0
2 2012-03-17 00:08:00   1   12.0
3 2012-03-17 00:10:00   2    NaN
4 2012-03-17 00:12:00   2    2.0
5 2012-03-17 00:20:00   2    8.0
6 2012-03-20 00:43:00   3    NaN
```

Comment: Notice - first row equal 6 not Nan, need to change order